# Functions that are convex after monotonic change of variables

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider a multivariate function $y = f(x_1,...,x_n)$. Suppose there exist monotonic functions $h_i, g$, such that the function:

$$F(y_1,...,y_n) = g(f(h_1(y_1), ..., h_n(y_n)))$$

is convex.

Is there a name for functions $f$ satisfying this property? In this sense they are "almost convex".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the functions you are describing are [quasiconvex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function).

For univariate functions, these are equivalent classes, I think. For multivariate functions, it's less clear to me. Maybe instead of monotonic functions in each variable, you should replace with [cyclical monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclical_monotonicity)?

---

NOTE: Based on comments by Calvin below, it should be required that $h$ and $g$ be homeomorphisms (I think continuity + strict monotonicity + surjectivity suffice in $\mathbb{R}$), for equivalence to quasiconvexity in the 1D case. See comments for counterexamples otherwise.

Comment: They are not the same as quasiconvex functions because the monotone functions may not be bijective; let $f$ be $x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ and not quasiconvex on $\mathbb R$. Then set $h(x) = \tanh x$ and $g(x) = (\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{|x|})^2 \operatorname{sgn}(x)$. Both are monotone on $\mathbb R$. Result of compositions is $gfh(x) = x^2$ which is convex.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example as $x^2$ is convex on $[-1,1]$. The more general point is well-taken however, especially if monotonicity is not strict. In this case, we could just ask $h$ or $g$ to be constant, and one can get a convex function from any $f$. Even if strict monotonicity holds, you could easily construct non-bijective $h$ that allows one to "skip" over the non-quasiconvex parts of $f$. I've added a note above that homeomorphism should really be required here.

Comment: Well i was thinking say $f(x) = x^2 $ for $x<1$ and $2-|x|$ for $x\ge 1$, $f\in C^0$, $f$ is convex on $[-1,1]$, its not quasiconvex on $\mathbb R$, and its almost convex in the sense of OP by earlier comment. And yes a constant function is even better

Comment: That makes more sense. Though I think the $h$ and $g$ are perhaps more complicated than necessary? I figured that if you use $h = -\sqrt{|x|}$ for $x \leq 0$, and $h = 2 + x$ otherwise, then $f(h(x)) = -x$ which is convex.

Comment: Also true! $\quad$